# How to find Table Creator and table creation date/time

Tags: hive, ambari

How do I find the creator of a VIEW along with the timestamp?

Also, how do I find out last modifier name and timestamp for VIEW ?

Answer (score 1):

use the following query; this will give you the information regrading timestamp:

```
describe extended <Table_name>;
```

Comment: Hi Tanvir, If its  view then how to get the View last access time and modified time.